# mysql error with a trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a trigger which will be executed when a new row is about to be inserted if my condition is satisfied ( latest version = 1 ) all previous row will be updated with latest version = 0

```
CREATE TRIGGER remiseazero
BEFORE INSERT 
ON wp_stattype2_3_activite
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.latestversion = 1
THEN
update wp_stattype2_3_activite
set latestversion = 0 where typecas = new.typecas;
END IF;
END;$$
```

**Error:**

> **#1064** - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9

Comment: How are you creating your trigger? via phpMyAdmin? If so, have you indicated to phpMyAdmin that $$ is supposed to be your delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put delimiter. And remove `;` after `END`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER remiseazero
BEFORE INSERT 
ON wp_stattype2_3_activite
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.latestversion = 1) THEN
    update wp_stattype2_3_activite set latestversion = 0 where typecas = NEW.typecas;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: @user3581207 Solve the problem?